# percentage analysis in quartiles

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get the maximum, minimum of the difference between t3 and t3 in each quartile. But when I change the percentage # to 50,75.. I see the output listed below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
SELECT MIN(SPREAD),MAX(SPREAD) FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*)*1.0 AS TOTALLINES FROM pa_fcs)A,
  (SELECT SPREAD,ROWNUM *1.0 AS LINENUM FROM (
select BOARD_RATE_T3,BOARD_RATE_T1 ,(BOARD_RATE_T3-BOARD_RATE_T1) AS SPREAD 
  from  pa_fcs ))B 
  WHERE LINENUM/TOTALLINES <= .25;

OUTPUT: .25
Min(Spread)      Max(Spread)
7.47             5160.24

Output :.50
Min(Spread)      Max(Spread)
7.47             5160.24

Output: .75
Min(Spread)      Max(Spread)
0              5160.24
```

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with those results?  You are not ordering the records you query from `pa_fcs', so it's possible the row with the highest spread is in the first quarter of the rows and the row with the lowest spread is in the 3rd quarter of the rows.

Comment: *not ordering the records* **is the problem** @MatthewMcPeak

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I know :)  That was my roundabout way to get the OP to realize that that might be the case, since she did not include her expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NTILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm) analytic function to calculate the quartiles.

Then is `MIN`, `MAX` trivial exersize

```
create table tab as
select rownum spread from dual connect by level <= 100;

with ntile as (
select 
    spread,
    NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY spread DESC)  qtile
from tab)
select qtile, min(spread), max(spread)
from ntile
group by qtile order by 1
;

     QTILE MIN(SPREAD) MAX(SPREAD)
---------- ----------- -----------
         1          76         100
         2          51          75
         3          26          50
         4           1          25
```

For your table it would be something like

```
with spr as (
  select  (BOARD_RATE_T3-BOARD_RATE_T1) AS SPREAD 
  from  pa_fcs),
ntile as (
  select 
    spread,
    NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY spread DESC)  qtile
  from spr)
select qtile, min(spread), max(spread)
from ntile
group by qtile order by 1
```

Comment: select rownum, SPREAD 
     from dual connect by level <= 100;

     with ntile as (
     select 
    (BOARD_RATE_T3-BOARD_RATE_T1) as spread,
    NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY spread DESC)  qtile
from pa_fcs)
     select qtile, min(spread), max(spread)
     from ntile
     group by qtile order by 1
      ;

Comment: This query isn't working it says spread is an invalid identifier

Comment: @Amelia added query for your table in the answer